# 404 Not Found on Jquery AJAX JSON PHP POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to POST some JSON data to a local host and I keep getting a 404 Not Found error which is strange because the php file is located in the correct location as specified in the script. I would appreciate any feedback from anyone who has experience with this. Am I getting this error because the the server can not locate the ajax.php file for some unknown reason?

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="text-muted">AJAX JSON Data</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="data-div">
                <form method="post" action="api/ajax.php" class="ajax">
                    <p><label for="firstname" class="contact-input-text">First Name</label> <br/>
                    <input id="first-name" name="firstname" type="text" maxlength="30" autofocus /></p><p><label for="lastName" class="contact-input-text">Last Name</label> <br/>
                    <input id="last-name" name="lastname" type="text" maxlength="30" autofocus /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="contact-input-text" value="submit" /></p>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

<script>
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
            
            var jsondata = {};
            $(this).find('[name]').each(function(i, data){
                console.log(data);
                var that = $(this); 
                var key = that.attr('name');
                var value = that.val();
                jsondata[key] = value;
            });
            console.log(jsondata);

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: jsondata,
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr){
                    console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
            return false;

</script>
```

Here is the ajax.php file....

```html
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $file = "data.json";
  $json_string = json_encode($_POST,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents($file,$json_string,FILE_APPEND);
 }
?>
```

This is the directory structure :

```
index.html (contains the form input fields and the ajax request)
ajax.php
/styles
/images
```

Comment: First of all, no need for `action="api/ajax.php"` in your form as you are doing Ajax request. Second of all, where is your file `ajax.php`? In `.`, in `./api/`?

Comment: @D4V1D - thanks. The ajax.php is located in the same directory as the script file.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the exact tree view of your folders where the files are?

Comment: @Toshi Paths specified in a script are applied as relative to the document / current `location`.

Comment: Is `ajax.php` located in the same directory as the `js` file or the `html` file?

Comment: @D4V1D - The ajax.php file is in the same directory as the html file. The javascript is embedded in the html file.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks.. see above posting.

Comment: Cannot see where it could go wrong if both your files are located in the same directory. Can you edit your question with a screenshot of the tree view deployed so we can have a deeper look at your files?

Comment: Can you transcript this screenshot with symbols and letter and copy that to your question?

Comment: @D4V1D - https://www.flickr.com/photos/68642514@N06/16937537855/   I will transcript this screenshot to my question.

Comment: And `index.html` is the file with the form and the `js` ajax code?

Comment: @D4V1D - correct. the html code contains the ajax code and the form input fields. The ajax code is nested in <script> tags.

Comment: What does `console.log(xhr)` outputs then?

Comment: @D4V1d - it returns responseText : Cannot POST /ajax.php & statustext : Not Found

Comment: I am running this locally on a grunt server.

Comment: Can you try setting `url: '/ajax.php',`? (note the `/` before `ajax.php`).

Comment: @D4V1D - yes I have tried that before and didn't seem to work.

Comment: Just ran a test locally as per your configuration, everything went well. There's something you're not telling us which would be relevant to the situation here.

Comment: @ D4V1D - I think it might have something to do with my local server which is running on localhost:9000 on a grunt server. I uploaded the file to my remote server and it seems to work. Now I get a responsetext that is telling me about an error in my php script.. Any insight as to why this would not work on my local server? Sorry I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

have you ensure with correct url in ajax?

maybe not thi:

```
url: 'ajax.php'
```

but this:

```
url: 'api/ajax.php'
```

Comment: Please avoid answering the question if you don't plan on actually **answering** the question but rather asking for info. Use comments for that.

Comment: As there is `return false` in his function `.on('submit',`, these attributes are **not used at all**.

Comment: maybe wrong url in ajax code,
from
url: 'ajax.php'
become
url: 'api/ajax.php'

Comment: @D4V1D, please back my reputation :)